# Reznors in Super Mario World?

Tags: super-mario-world

Why is there the word "Reznor" displayed on the rhino boss levels in Super Mario World?

Comment: The name of the rhino boss. Also, to defeat it, just hit the blocks below! Just saying ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's [the name of the rhino bosses](http://www.mariowiki.com/Reznor).

Answer (score 6):

In an update to http://www.mariowiki.com/Reznor from July 18 2012, Dayvv Brooks (a former Nintendo of America employee) has stated that the Reznors (who are actually triceratopses) are named after Trent Reznor of the industrial rock band Nine Inch Nails. This is similar to how the Koopalings are named after other musicians.